# Change border div depending on where user click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

On my website, data is displayed in a horizontal list. Each individual list item has a title and a button.
I've displayed it here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-platform-vj5td9

My task is that when you click on a div (id="main") with the value "first element", the color of the border changes from green to red. When you click on a div (id="main") with a value of "second element", the red color of the border with the "first element" is removed (and becomes green as before) and the border becomes red instead of the green of the "second element". However, when clicking on the "submenu" button, the border should not turn red.

```
    const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "first element" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element" },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div id="main" className="App">
          <div id="text">{item.title}</div>
          <button>submenu</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you don't understand something from my explanations, don't hesitate to write to me.

Comment: What have you tried before? Do you have any progress, any error messages? Please provides us with more info, as Stackoverflow is not a "please do this" forum, rather its about finding solutions to specific problems for others to find.

Comment: @PatrickCerny Yes, before asking the question, I tried some options. But it turns out that when I click on one div, all of them light up red. I still don’t know how to process a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems with your posted JSX, which we'll discuss before looking at my proposed solution to the problem.

So, the original code with explanatory, and critical, comments in the code:

```
const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "first element" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element" },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    /*   here you're returning the contents wrapped in a <div>.
         element; this isn't necessarily a problem but be aware
         of the potential for creating a mess of unnecessary
         <div> elements: */
    <div>
      /*   here we're looping over the data defined above,
           which is okay, except... */
      {data.map((item) => (
        /*   we're creating two elements, each of which have
             an 'id' attribute, and there are multiple of
             these elements in the eventual HTML, which
             is invalid (an id must be unique within the
             document): */
        <div id="main" className="App">
          <div id="text">{item.title}</div>
          <button>submenu</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My proposed solution, then, is as follows:

```jsx
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "first element" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element" },
];
// defining a named function to handle the click
// event, using an Arrow function expression,
// which passes a reference to the Event Object
// to the function:
const clickHandler = (evt) => {
  // we retrieve all elements within the document that
  // have the 'activated' class-name:
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".activated")
    // and use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate
    // over each of those elements and remove that
    // class-name:
    .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("activated"));

  // we then use the currentTarget property-value of
  // the Event Object ('evt'), access its classList
  // and add the class of 'activated':
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("activated");
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    /*   here we use a fragment to avoid returning the
         an unnecessary <div>: /*
    <>
      {
        /*   we define the <div id="main"> element 
             outside of the loop that generates the
             content: */
        <div id="main" className="App">
          {data.map((item) => (
           /*  here we avoid using id attributes, and 
               instead use meaningful class-names (though
               obviously you may wish to rename the
               classes for your own use).
               We then use the onClick approach to bind a
               function (clickHandler) to the 'click' event
               fired on the elements; I personally dislike
               inline event-handling but it seems the
               preferred means of doing it within React;
               also (as I was preparing to finalise this)
               I realised that React was complaining that
                 "Each child in a list should have a unique
                 "key" prop", so I added the "key" prop as
                well: */
            <div className="menu-element-card" onClick={clickHandler} key={item.id}>
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              /*   in the even that these elements may,
                   in some circumstances, be nested within
                   a <form> I've taken the liberty of
                   adding 'type="button"' to the <button>
                   elements to prevent default/unintended
                   form-submission: */
              <button type="button">sub-menu</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        <!-- closing the <div id="main"> element: -->
        </div>
      }
    <!-- closing the fragment: -->
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, I updated the stylesheet to the following; purely for aesthetics – please adjust for your own needs – in order to make the borders a little more prominent and spread the elements out a little:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.menu-element-card {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-inline-start-width: 0.3rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-block-end: 0.4rem;
  padding-block: 0.4rem;
  padding-inline-start: 0.5rem;
  transition: border-color 300ms linear;
}

.activated {
  border-inline-start-color: red;
}
```

[Codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nameless-glitter-89yfwp?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A1%2C1-19%2C1).

With reference to the question from OP, in the comments:

> in the condition I wrote that pressing the submenu button should not change the color of the border. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Of course, I missed that requirement; in response though I've adjusted the `clickHandler()` function to the following:

```jsx
const clickHandler = (evt) => {
  /* the evt.target is the element upon which the event
     was triggered, here we're checking that that
     element is not a <button>, and that the element
     does not have an ancestor <button> element */
  if (evt.target.matches(":not(button)") && !evt.target.closest("button")) {
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".activated")
      .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("activated"));
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("activated");
  }
};
```

[Codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nameless-glitter-89yfwp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A31%2C51).

Further, in response to the additional comment from OP (below):

> ...can I change the content of divs depending on whether the div is active or not. For example: if the user clicks on a div and the border color changes from green to red, then within the divs the message “color changed” will be displayed?

This is certainly possible, and in (at least) a couple of ways depending on your requirements.

The first is primarily to use CSS, and a pseudo-element although obviously JavaScript is in use as it's React:

````jsx
const data = [
  // here I've added an additional property ('msg') to some
  // of the Objects in the data Array in order to show how
  // we can accommodate elements without a specified message:
  { id: "1", title: "first element", msg: "Item 1 was activated" },
  { id: "2", title: "second element" },
  { id: "3", title: "third element", msg: "Item 3 was activated" },
];

const clickHandler = (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.matches(":not(button)") && !evt.target.closest("button")) {
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".activated")
      .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("activated"));
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("activated");
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        <div id="main" className="App">
          {data.map((item) => (
            <div
              className="menu-element-card"
              // here we add a 'data-message' attribute
              // (a prop could be used of course) to store
              // the required message in the HTML which
              // exposes that content to the CSS:
              data-message={item.msg}
              onClick={clickHandler}
              key={item.id}
            >
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              <button type="button">
                sub-menu <span>nested element text</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
}```


```lang-css
.App {
  /* here we define one (of a few, throughout the file)
     custom CSS properties which can be used in multiple
     places: */
  --transitionDuration: 300ms;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.menu-element-card {
  /* defining more custom properties, this time in the
     scope of their likely use:
      */
  --accentBorderColor: hsl(0deg 70% 50% / 1);
  --accentBorderWidth: 0.3rem;
  --baseBorderColor: lime;
  /* defining the borders with the various custom
     properties, via the CSS var() function:
     */
  border: 2px solid var(--baseBorderColor);
  border-inline-start: var(--accentBorderWidth) solid var(--baseBorderColor);
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-block-end: 0.4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-block: 0.4rem;
  padding-inline-start: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  /* defining the transition: */
  transition: border-color var(--transitionDuration) linear;

  /* using native CSS nesting to style the ::before
     pseudo-element of the .menu-element-card */
  &::before {
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      hsl(240deg 90% 80% / 1),
      hsl(300deg 90% 80% / 1)
    );
    block-size: fit-content;
    border-block-end: var(--accentBorderWidth) solid var(--baseBorderColor);
    content: attr(data-message);
    /* using inset to position the pseudo-element 0
       distance from the top, right, bottom and left
       edges: */
    inset: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all var(--transitionDuration) linear;
    /* positioning the element outside of its parent: */
    translate: 0 calc(-1 * (100% + var(--accentBorderWidth)));
    /* specifying the properties which should transition
       (assuming you want transitions, obviously): */
    transition-property: border-color, translate;
  }

  &:not([data-message])::before {
    /* those elements that do not have a data-message
       attribute are not displayed: */
    display: none;
  }
}

.activated {
  border-inline-start-color: var(--accentBorderColor);
  &::before {
    border-block-end-color: var(--accentBorderColor);
    translate: 0 0;
  }
}```

[Codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nameless-glitter-89yfwp?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A1%2C1-48%2C2).

Alternatively, there's the option of using the same `items` Array of Objects, and the following JSX:

```lang-jsx
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        <div id="main" className="App">
          {data.map((item) => (
            <div
              className="menu-element-card"
              onClick={clickHandler}
              key={item.id}
            >
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              /* here we use a ternary operator to test if
                 the 'msg' property exists on the 'item'
                 Object; if it does we return the <p> element
                 with the that text, and a specified class,
                 otherwise we return null so that no empty
                 <p> elements are created: */
              {item.msg ? <p class="activeMessage">{item.msg}</p> : null}
              <button type="button">
                sub-menu <span>nested element text</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
}```

[Codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nameless-glitter-89yfwp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A35%2C14).

Obviously there is some simple CSS to hide, and reveal, the `p.activeMessage` element.
````

Comment: First of all, thank you for paying attention to my question. Secondly, I am grateful to you for such a detailed answer with explanations. Here I gave a very schematic example of my problem, and after your explanation I applied everything in my working code and it works. Thank you! Just a small point: in the condition I wrote that pressing the submenu button should not change the color of the border. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Comment: And one more small clarification. Here, in the example, I use css, but in the working version I use tailwind. Can I somehow change css to tailwind in your solution?

Comment: I've edited the answer to address the problems with the `<button>`, as for using Tailwind then there's no reason not to, you'd just have to import it into the application and use an appropriate class-name(s). I don't use Tailwind (I don't really see the point of it), so I can't offer any substantial advice on that aspect.

Comment: Thanks for the addition and clarification. I will certainly accept your answer. I would like to clarify another small point: can I change the content of divs depending on whether the div is active or not. For example: if the user clicks on a div and the border color changes from green to red, then within the divs the message “color changed” will be displayed.

Comment: I've added the relevant information to address that last comment question, any other questions and information should - quite probably - be part of a new question. A new question that includes the requirements in the initial question (a question can be edited to add information, and update requirements so long as the changes don't invalidate existing answers ).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the border of a `div` depending on where the user clicks, you can achieve this using JavaScript. Here's a simple example using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

```js
function changeBorder(event) {
  // Get the clicked div
  const clickedDiv = event.target;

  // Get the current border color
  const currentBorderColor = window.getComputedStyle(clickedDiv).borderColor;

  // Change the border color based on the click position
  if (event.clientX < clickedDiv.offsetWidth / 2) {
    // Left half of the div
    clickedDiv.style.borderLeftColor = "red";
    clickedDiv.style.borderRightColor = currentBorderColor;
  } else {
    // Right half of the div
    clickedDiv.style.borderRightColor = "blue";
    clickedDiv.style.borderLeftColor = currentBorderColor;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .clickable-div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Change Border on Click</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv" class="clickable-div" onclick="changeBorder(event)">
    Click me to change the border!
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

In this example, the `changeBorder` function is called when the `div` is clicked. The function checks the horizontal position of the click (`event.clientX`) relative to the width of the `div` to determine if the left or right side was clicked. It then changes the border color accordingly.

You can customize this example based on your specific requirements and styling preferences.

Comment: He is using react and your answer should reflect that. Your post does not answer the question nor is it relevant. Please read the questions fully before responding.